# Exclude tests from xctool

Tags: ios, unit-testing, continuous-integration, xctool

Is it possible to exclude a specific unit test or test suite from [`xctool`](https://github.com/facebook/xctool)?

I noticed that `xctool` allows me to specify specific tests to run with the `-only` flag. I would like to do the opposite.

The reason is that some tests require components that are not available in the console test environment.

If there is no flag to do this (I couldn't find any in the documentation), what would be the best alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a new scheme (`RMStoreExcludeKeychingTests`) including the same targets from the original scheme and excluding the offending tests (shown below in Xcode 5).

[image]

Finally, I told `xctool` to use the new scheme for testing. This way, if I add new tests and code I don't have to make any changes to the schemes or targets.

In case it's of any help, the schemes can be found [here](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore/tree/master/RMStore.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes) and the Travis CI configuration with the `xctool` invocation [here](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore/blob/master/.travis.yml).

Answer (score 1):

There is an `omit` command now.

From the doc:

```
-omit SPEC                 SPEC is TARGET[:Class/case[,Class2/case2]]; use * when specifying class or case prefix.
```